# How to position widgets inside column in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have two widgets to be placed inside column. The first widget is a TabbarView widget, whose content could be long. The second widget is a TabBar. I want the tabbar to stay always at the bottom of the column and allot the remaining space to TabbarView widget.

Suggest a solution other than using Flex.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick work around, you can try wrapping your `TabbarView` in a container and giving it a height using `Mediaquery.of(context).size.height * .94`
then for the remaining space add your `TabBar`

Comment: Giving a static value as .94 wont work because columns height varies with device screen sizes. Hence it causes bottom overflow issue

Comment: thats a percentage value which means in all devices it will occupy 94% of the screen

Comment: I do understand that it is a % value but i don't have all the screen space available for the column. My column starts from around middle of the screen height as i have another widgets on top of the tree. So the column height is not fixed. I would like to arrange the widgets in the available column space, with TabBar always at the bottom of the column